# How can I make a concentric pattern of circles in my WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am having trouble trying to make the circles into concentric pattern. For example, the next circle bigger, then bigger and so on. A bit like the core, inner core, outer core, and crust of the earth.

Below is all of my code:

```
namespace ClickAppearBalls
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Random randClick;
        private Graphics paper;
        private Pen pen;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            randClick = new Random();
            paper = picCanvas.CreateGraphics();

        }

        private void picCanvas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x, y, size1, size2;

            x = picCanvas.Height / 2;
            y = picCanvas.Width / 2;

            Color color = Color.FromArgb(randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256));
            Pen pen = new Pen(color);
            pen.Width = 3;
            size1 = 30;
            size2 = 30;
            paper.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, size1, size2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the size variable on the class so that it can be used on consecutive clicks. Then you need to increase it with every click.

```
namespace ClickAppearBalls
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Random randClick;
        private Graphics paper;
        private Pen pen;
        private int circleSize = 30;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            randClick = new Random();
            paper = picCanvas.CreateGraphics();

        }

        private void picCanvas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x, y;

            x = picCanvas.Height / 2;
            y = picCanvas.Width / 2;

            Color color = Color.FromArgb(randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256), randClick.Next(0, 256));
            Pen pen = new Pen(color);
            pen.Width = 3;
            paper.DrawEllipse(pen, x - circleSize/2, y - circleSize/2, circleSize, circleSize);

            circleSize += 10; // increase size here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually you will need to go from the outside in shrinking, as the new layer will paint over the old one, so the new layer must be smaller if you you want to be able to see both layers (or repaint the inner layers).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No, as the circles are not filled. I checked that, it works, though I had to also move the middle point of the circle.

Comment: Right, I was thinking of a different function.

Comment: the suggestion works above but the circles seem to go towards the bottom right as a click, how could i make it so the cicles expanded in the middle not overlapping any ideas? thanks guys

Comment: I made a fix few minutes ago. You need to have `x - circleSize/2, y - circleSize/2` as the middle point for the circles.

Comment: can you explain how the x - circleSize/2 statement works??? am a new student to this thank you for your help

Comment: Check the definition of `DrawEllipse` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse(v=vs.110).aspx). You define the rectangle around it. So you have to move the top left point by half the radius of the circle to make circles concentric.

Comment: just another quick question if you dont mind my next task it to modify then program so wherever i click a circle of random color appears do i do this u x y coordinates??

Comment: Please ask a separate question. When you ask questions on this site, they have to be specific and contain one problem.